# Angular7 app not working in Safari Browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, angular7

I know this question has been asked many times but none of the method or approach mentioned worked for me.
I am using **ANGULAR 7** to build my project but its not working in all the versions of safari

Its not showing any error or warning.

Is there any way to detect my project is compatible with the browser or not? if yes please let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can target browser support in Angular uinsg `browserslist` file

```
# For IE 9-11 support, please uncomment the last line of the file and adjust as needed
> 0.5%
last 2 versions
Firefox ESR
safari 12.1
safari 12
not dead
# IE 9-11
```

You see that I'm target support version for safari 12 and 12.1 you can add version you want to support to that file

List of support browser can be found [here](https://browserl.ist/)